# Operation including tensor product or Kronecker product transforming matrix $A$ into matrix $B$

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, permutations, tensor-products

Given two matrices $A$ and $B$:

[image]

What transformation needs to be applied to transform matrix $A$ into matrix $B$?

```
A = {{0, c, b, -c + b c, a c, -a + a b, c + b c, a c, a + a b}, {0, c,
    b, c + b c, a c, a + a b, -c + b c, a c, -a + a b}, {0, -1, 0, b, 
   a, 0, b, a, 0}}

B = {{0, c, b, 0, c, b, 0, -1, 0}, {-c + b c, a c, -a + a b, c + b c, 
    a c, a + a b, b, a, 0}, {c + b c, a c, a + a b, -c + b c, 
    a c, -a + a b, b, a, 0}};
```

I mean the following. Find such a matrix X, or a pair of objects $x$ and $X$ for example (I don't know exactly how many are needed and what is the best formalism for this), so that either $AX=B$ or $xAX=B$ ?

I would be grateful for the advice, tk. until I found a suitable transformation.

**EDIT:**

I found one method that only uses $\frac{dQ}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$, and the result is the same as direct differentiation $\frac{dQ^T}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$. The disadvantage of this method is the need to glue the matrix again. Maybe I can get around this with some kind of unified tensor operation ? To immediately receive the entire matrix, without additional gluing.

```
Rx = RotationMatrix[\[Phi][t], {1, 0, 0}];

Ry = RotationMatrix[\[Xi][t], {0, 1, 0}];

Rz = RotationMatrix[\[Psi][t], {0, 0, 1}];

Q = Rz.Ry.Rx;

v = {\[Phi][t], \[Xi][t], \[Psi][t]};

T1 = Flatten /@ D[Q, {v}];

T2 = Flatten /@ D[Transpose[Q], {v}];

P1 = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
     0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

A1 = T1.{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
      0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};

A2 = T1.{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0,
      0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}};

A3 = T1.{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1,
      0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};

Transpose[P1.ArrayFlatten[{{A1}, {A2}, {A3}}]] == 
   Flatten /@ D[Transpose[Q], {v}] // MatrixForm;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linear transformation converting $A$ into $B$ is sometimes called the "realignment map" (see https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205017, for example): it is the linear transformation $R$ with the property that $R(\mathbf{e_i}\mathbf{e_j}^T \otimes \mathbf{e_k}\mathbf{e_\ell}^T) = \mathbf{e_i}\mathbf{e_k}^T \otimes \mathbf{e_j}\mathbf{e_\ell}^T$ for all $i$, $j$, $k$, and $\ell$.

The realignment map $R$ cannot be implemented by a single matrix multiplication on the left and right: there do not exist fixed matrices $X$ and $Y$ such that $XAY = B$. However, if you're comfortable with the partial transpose then you can write $R$ in the form
$$
R(A) = (A^\Gamma F)^\Gamma,
$$
where $F$ is the "commutation" or "flip" or "swap" matrix defined by $F(\mathbf{e_i} \otimes \mathbf{e_j}) = \mathbf{e_j} \otimes \mathbf{e_i}$ for all $i$ and $j$, and $\Gamma$ refers to the partial transpose (on the 2nd Kronecker factor): the map with the property that $(\mathbf{e_i}\mathbf{e_j}^T \otimes \mathbf{e_k}\mathbf{e_\ell}^T)^\Gamma = \mathbf{e_i}\mathbf{e_j}^T \otimes \mathbf{e_\ell}\mathbf{e_k}^T$ for all $i$, $j$, $k$, and $\ell$ (i.e., it transposes each $3 \times 3$ block of $A$).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Perhaps I need more time to study this method, I was expecting something simpler. Could you demonstrate the application of this procedure in Mathematica?

Comment: If you're just looking to code it up in something like Mathematica, it's probably easiest to just code up what happens to each entry individually. Think of it as having three 3x3 blocks: send the $(j,\ell)$-entry of the $k$-th block to the $(k,\ell)$-entry of the $j$-th block.

Comment: I'll try. Thank you for one of the possible ways.

Comment: Please, see my edit